# Describe return status of ping command

Tags: excel, vba

I use VBA to ping an IP from my system. The on/off result is not enough because if the ping result in real case is "reply from xx.xx.xx.xx destination host unreachable" but no packet loss, the ping tool will return "online" status.

When I try to describe return status of ping command I get

> "object variable or with block variable not set" - runtime error code 91

at:

```
Set objPing = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
  ("SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & Host & "' ")
```

```vb
Function GetPingResult(Host)

Dim objPing As Object
Dim objStatus As Object
Dim strResult As String

Set objPing = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
  ("SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & Host & "' ")

For Each objStatus In objPing
    Select Case objStatus.StatusCode
        Case 0: strResult = "Connected"
        Case 11001: strResult = "Buffer too small"
        Case 11002: strResult = "Destination net unreachable"
        Case 11003: strResult = "Destination host unreachable"
        Case 11004: strResult = "Destination protocol unreachable"
        Case 11005: strResult = "Destination port unreachable"
        Case 11006: strResult = "No resources"
        Case 11007: strResult = "Bad option"
        Case 11008: strResult = "Hardware error"
        Case 11009: strResult = "Packet too big"
        Case 11010: strResult = "Request timed out"
        Case 11011: strResult = "Bad request"
        Case 11012: strResult = "Bad route"
        Case 11013: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired transit"
        Case 11014: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired reassembly"
        Case 11015: strResult = "Parameter problem"
        Case 11016: strResult = "Source quench"
        Case 11017: strResult = "Option too big"
        Case 11018: strResult = "Bad destination"
        Case 11032: strResult = "Negotiating IPSEC"
        Case 11050: strResult = "General failure"
        Case Else: strResult = "Unknown host"
    End Select
    GetPingResult = strResult
Next
Set objPing = Nothing
End Function


Sub GetIPStatus()
Dim strMessage As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim ipRng As Range
Dim Result As String
Dim Wks As Worksheet
Dim strPostData As String
  
strChatID = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value

Set Wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set ipRng = Wks.Range("B2")
Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, ipRng.Column).End(xlUp)
Set ipRng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < ipRng.Row, ipRng, Wks.Range(ipRng, RngEnd))

Do Until Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "STOP"
    Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "TESTING"
    ' For Each Cell In ipRng
    For introw = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Result
        strMessage = ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 1).Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 2).Value & " is " & Result
        strPostData = "chat_id=" & strChatID & "&text=" & strMessage
        SendMessage (strPostData)
    ' Next Cell
    Next
Loop
Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "IDLE"
End Sub


Sub stop_ping()
    Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "STOP"
End Sub


Function SendMessage(strPostData)

Dim objRequest As Object
' Dim strChatID As String
' Dim strMessage As String
' Dim strPostData As String

' strChatID = 5779677248#
' strChatId = -834898784
' strMessage = "Hello"
' strPostData = "chat_id=" & strChatID & "&text=" & strMessage

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

With objRequest
    ' .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot5733265530:AAE0bZU_mJ8OZpZvEwn-gQExFf6GY-D8XWc/sendMessage?", False
    .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot5773569326:AAFpzQcdjIpsbd-IVCotXMucvpG4DpLfSVE/sendMessage?", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send (strPostData)  
End With
End Function
```

This is original working code I found. It failed when I added a sub to send code via telegram.

```vb
Function GetPingResult(Host)
   Dim objPing As Object
   Dim objStatus As Object
   Dim strResult As String

   Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"). _
     ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & Host & "'")

   For Each objStatus In objPing
       Select Case objStatus.StatusCode
           Case 0: strResult = "Connected"
           Case 11001: strResult = "Buffer too small"
           Case 11002: strResult = "Destination net unreachable"
           Case 11003: strResult = "Destination host unreachable"
           Case 11004: strResult = "Destination protocol unreachable"
           Case 11005: strResult = "Destination port unreachable"
           Case 11006: strResult = "No resources"
           Case 11007: strResult = "Bad option"
           Case 11008: strResult = "Hardware error"
           Case 11009: strResult = "Packet too big"
           Case 11010: strResult = "Request timed out"
           Case 11011: strResult = "Bad request"
           Case 11012: strResult = "Bad route"
           Case 11013: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired transit"
           Case 11014: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired reassembly"
           Case 11015: strResult = "Parameter problem"
           Case 11016: strResult = "Source quench"
           Case 11017: strResult = "Option too big"
           Case 11018: strResult = "Bad destination"
           Case 11032: strResult = "Negotiating IPSEC"
           Case 11050: strResult = "General failure"
           Case Else: strResult = "Unknown host"
       End Select
       GetPingResult = strResult
   Next

   Set objPing = Nothing
End Function


Sub GetIPStatus()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ipRng As Range
    Dim Result As String
    Dim Wks As Worksheet

    Set Wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set ipRng = Wks.Range("B3")
    Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, ipRng.Column).End(xlUp)
    Set ipRng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < ipRng.Row, ipRng, Wks.Range(ipRng, RngEnd))

    For Each Cell In ipRng
        Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Result
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the second half of that line on its own line? That way you can check `objPing` to see if `GetObject` returned a value, or if it returned nothing. If it returns nothing, then you cannot use `ExecQuery` at all.

Comment: To clarify: the line-continuation in your second block of code is not "on its own line" even tho visually it is in the editor - you need to add an intermediary step between setting `objPing` and calling `ExecQuery` on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Check `objPing` to see if `GetObject` returned an object first.

If it returns nothing, then you cannot use `ExecQuery` at all.

```
Dim objPing As Object
Dim objQuery As Object
Dim objStatus as Object

Set objPing = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}")
If Not objPing Is Nothing Then
  Set objQuery = objPing.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & Host & "' ")
  If Not objQuery Is Nothing Then ' not sure this can return nothing, but it doesn't hurt to check
    For Each objStatus In objQuery

      ' [... rest of your code here ...]

    Next
  Else
    Msgbox "Nothing found for : " & Host
  End If
Else
  Msgbox "Cannot Impersonate"
End If
```

Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/setting-the-default-process-security-level-using-vbscript